# entity framework configuration addorupdate many-to-many seed records

Tags: entity-framework, many-to-many, seed

Defining the many-to-many relationship is not the problem.
I have a Rooms table (like rooms in a house) and each of these can have one or more colors from a Colors table.
Each has a List reference to the opposite table - see classes below.

In the Configuration class, Seed method, I am creating the various tables using AddOrUpdate.

```
            ctx.Rooms.AddOrUpdate(r => new { r.Name, r.HouseId },
            new Room
            {
                Name = "Kitchen",
                House = (from h in ctx.Houses where h.Address == "Littleton, MA" select h).First(),
                HouseId = (from h in ctx.Houses where h.Address == "Littleton, MA" select h.HouseId).First()
            });
```

(followed by ctx.SaveChanges of course)

And I can create many colors the same way:

```
            ctx.Colors.AddOrUpdate(c => new { c.ColorName },
            new Color
            {
                ColorName = "Green"
            });
```

With each room, I want to associate one or more of the colors.

[image]
(In SQL:)
[image]
Colors:
[image]
[image]

EF creates the table relating the two in the many-to-many relationship.

[image]

It seems like this should be easy, but I can't find a way and I have searched the web as well.
Thanks for your help.
:-)

Comment: I didn't see a question in all that?

Comment: Hi, LOL so sorry... First, I was trying to using AddOrUpdate to seed a Room and specify the colors it has.  Second, I am trying to use linq to CREATE a Room and specify the color(s) that are associated with that.

Comment: Room.Colors.Add(Color color). Make sure you are initializing your list in the Room constructor.

Comment: Post this as the proposed answer so I can check it and thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you are initializing your list in the Room constructor

```
public class Room
{
   public Room()
   {
      Colors = new List<Color>();
   }
   // properties omitted
   public virtual IList<Color> Colors {get;set;}
}
```

Then just call

```
room.Colors.Add(Color color);
```

This is will add a color to your list.

This isn't the best solution as you should encapsulate your collections so that your aren't bypassing any business rules but EF 6 makes it [difficult](https://ardalis.com/exposing-private-collection-properties-to-entity-framework).

EF core makes it much [easier](https://ardalis.com/encapsulated-collections-in-entity-framework-core).